# javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, wildfly

I'm migrating my application from jboss4.0.2 to wildfly_9.0.1, and I'm getting the below error into wildfly startup:

```
        
"{\"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./awomweb\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./awomweb: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Parser configuration exception parsing XML from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [__redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory@4b93a3] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.

            Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitioStoreException: Parser configuration exception parsing XML from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [__redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory@4b93a3] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.
```

here is my applicationContext.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">


       ---Another---code----


    </beans>
```

How to fix this?